# React Native return value inside then()

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

I am trying to return the value from `AsyncStorage` without using the `async` function and `await`. When I use the below function, however, it returns `undefined`. Thank you in advance!

```
getAllFav(){
    var collect;
    const value = AsyncStorage.getAllKeys().then(
        (values) => {
            collect=values;
            return collect;
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: in the topic you mentioned is not explained how can i return the calue inside then.

Comment: Right. Because the answers there quite clearly say you can't do that (so naturally they don't then say how to do the thing you can't do). They **do** tell you what to do instead, such as making `getAllFav` return a promise. You can't magically convert an asynchronous operation into a synchronous one.